# Heroku app crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I've just deployed my RoR app to Heroku, and the app works on my local port, but when I visit the Heroku address I get:

> App crashed This application is temporarily offline. If you're the
>   administrator of this app, please check your heroku logs for the
>   backtrace.

This may be the error that I found in the logs:

```
2011-02-25T17:08:25-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET afternoon-warrior-452.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-02-25T17:08:25-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET afternoon-warrior-452.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>My guess is that you forgot to set up the production database. Perhaps...</sup>

<sup>`$ heroku rake db:setup` or `$ heroku rake db:push`  ...is needed?</sup>

*Update:* Aha! Going by your error message in the comment, you have an unresolved merge conflict in `application_helper.rb.` That's what those `<<<<<<` lines are, something inserted by git (or perhaps some local SCCS you are using) that usually point out conflicts between a branch and local changes.

Start with "git status" and also just look at `application_helper.rb` in your editor.

Comment: No I don't think this is it. Check out some of the logs I've reproduced below jdl's answer. The error may be in there.

Comment: ahh yes, i think this is it. But I thought I had fixed the merge conflict manually...

Comment: `# modified:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb`
`# modified:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
This is what I get referring to `application_helper.rb` when I run `git status` I originally cleaned up those `<<<<<<` in my text editor but I'm guessing that wasn't enough. Not sure what to do now though.

Comment: ahhh ok! Just figured it out. Thanks digitalross!

Answer (score 0):

`$ heroku logs --app app_name` might give you something to go on, but don't expect too much. The logs are pretty sparse.

You could use the Exceptional add-on to maybe get some more info. There is also the "Logging" add-on, which I have not tried yet, but might be of help to you.

Also pay attention to the messages you get when you do your `git push` to Heroku. Make sure that all of your gems are installing properly.

Comment: I found this from the logs. Could this be the error? `2011-02-25T17:08:25-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET afternoon-warrior-452.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-02-25T17:08:25-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET afternoon-warrior-452.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0`

Comment: That only tells us that there was an error, not really what happened. Trying running `heroku restart` and then `heroku logs` right away to see if anything interesting shows up.

Comment: Here's some strange stuff: `2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]: /app/8d489c6f-7838-45ee-bc56-f2e2e72a0a94/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in require': /app/8d489c6f-7838-45ee-bc56-f2e2e72a0a94/home/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]:   ^`

Comment: `2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]: /app/8d489c6f-7838-45ee-bc56-f2e2e72a0a94/home/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting kEND
2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]: <<<<<<< HEAD
2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]: /app/8d489c6f-7838-45ee-bc56-f2e2e72a0a94/home/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected tEQQ, expecting $end
2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]:    ^
2011-02-25T17:09:08-08:00 app[web.1]: =======`

Comment: Looks like a code bug. Post your `application_helper.rb` file in your original question and let's see. How well is this app unit tested, because something like that should be blowing up on any functional test case.