# I'm having trouble with heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have a ruby app that works fine locally but after pushing it to Heroku it crashes. It's a very simple one that uses net/http to GET some info from an API (desk.com) and display it for me. This is the log:

```
2013-11-22T05:42:37.318570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=case-count.herokuapp.com fwd="204.244.194.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-22T05:42:37.626109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=case-count.herokuapp.com fwd="204.244.194.82" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes=
```

Even if you can't give me the exact solution, do you at least know any better ways to troubleshoot this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku app crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124272/heroku-app-crashing)

Comment: Try running `heroku restart` and then `heroku logs` right away to see if anything interesting shows up. You can also open a different terminal and enter `heroku logs --tail` and perform the restart in another session.

Comment: Did you migrate the database?